# How do you bake ambient occlusion for a model?

Tags: texture-baking, ambient-occlusion

I have a model and I need to bake ambient occlusion for it. How do I bake an AO texture?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### First you need to UV unwrap the model so the texture can be baked

You should do this manually if you plan to need to create a real texture and you want a clean unwrapping. If you only need an AO map, Blender can do it for you automatically.

First, split the viewport by clicking and dragging the grip found in the top right corner of the 3D viewport out from the left to the center of the window. Set the new viewport to the *UV/Image Editor*:

[image: UV/Image Editor]

Now Hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter *Edit Mode*.

With your cursor over the *3D Viewport*, hit <kbd>A</kbd> once or twice so that the whole model is selected (orange).

With your cursor still over the *3D Viewport*, hit <kbd>U</kbd> and click *Lightmap Pack*. Enable *New Image* and set the resolution to a power of two that you want the lightmap's image to be.

You should now have a UV unwrapping in the *UV/Image Editor* viewport.

#### Next, set the material to pure white if desired

If you plan to use this ambient occlusion map as an overlay in an actual diffuse texture that you create, you want the flat parts of the surface to appear pure white so that they are pure transparent when overlaid with a multiply blend mode. By default, the ambient occlusion texture bake will include the color of the surface which is the default gray. To fix this, go to the *Material* tab and drag the *color* up to pure white and the *intensity* up to 1.000.

[image]
*Upper box: drag the circle all the way up to pure white*
*Lower box: drag the intensity box to the right until it reaches 1.000*

#### Now you can set up the actual texture baking

Under the *World* tab, enable *Ambient Occlusion* and then set the *Samples* under the *Gather* section to a number that you like. The higher the number, the higher the lightmap quality but consequently the higher the bake time. You may want to set it to something lower such as 20 for test bakes before you create a final bake at a higher setting such as 128.

[image: Samples]

Next, go to the *Render* tab and under the *Bake* section, set the *Bake Mode* to *Ambient Occlusion*. Then hit the *Bake* button and wait as the ambient occlusion map is baked for you.

[image: Bake Mode: Ambient Occlusion]

You can watch the progress as the texture is created in the *UV/Image Editor* and the progress bar at the top of Blender.

[image: Texture Bake progress]

When it is done baking, leave *Edit Mode* by hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> and setting the *Viewport Shading* to *Texture*.

[image: Viewport Shading: Texture]

You can now see your model with ambient occlusion!

[image: Model with ambient occlusion texture]
*Note the gray: this will occur if you do not set the material to white prior to baking as described above*

You can now export this texture from the *UV/Image Editor* by clicking *Image* > *Save As Image*.

[image: Image > Save As Image]

Then just name the file, choose a format, select a file location, and hit *Save As Image*.

Comment: As I've seen noone haven' t thanked you for this very nice detailed guide, I feel you truly earn some "thanks" words, really  :)

Thanks for this nice guide.

Comment: Okay how do you smooth it out, i've got aliasing all over mine even though I had 20 samples

Comment: @cubrman You probably want several hundred samples.