# weird ambient occlusion shadow

Tags: texture-baking

i've been working on a small oven model and i have a problem with the AO bake,
for whatever reason there is a big round shadow in middle of the front and i have no ida what causing it.

Here is a screenshot of what i mean

[image: Here is a screenshot of what i mean]

and on the rendered ao texture

[image: ao texture]

any idea whats happening?

edit:
i'm using blender render with approximate setting

edit2:
blend file
[image]

[image]

Comment: something burning in your oven? :) Check for hidden geometry

Comment: Are you using BI or cycles? To me it looks a bit like the artifacts you see with *approximate* gather in BI.

Comment: Did you change anything in world settings? The attenuation and falloff?

Comment: Could you maybe post a .blend file?

Comment: you can use this link to upload a [.blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me it looks like a somehow artifact of Approximate method of calculating AO. If you slower `Error` value in Approximate settings, you will likely get rid of this effect (and increase your baking time):

[image]

(I added Edge Split modifier here)

If using Raytrace method (like it's already described [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13956/how-do-you-bake-ambient-occlusion-for-a-model)), results will be similar, but at the same time you'll have more control over settings (actually, over baking time):

[image]

[.blend](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/35080)

Comment: alright thanks that fix'ed it. i just have a small question about the raytrace mode; is there anyway i can make it less grainy and more smooth like the approximate mode?

Comment: @Delcard, only by increasing Samples value (and increasing bake time). In fact, it means that if one has 24 seconds to bake using 10 samples (for this model), then he will have 35 sec using 12 samples (as I've count). It's not critical on relatively simple models and as always - one should plan whether he needs high quality and a bunch of samples (and bake time) or it's not so important.