# How do I overlay a lightmap image on another texture?

Tags: texturing, uv

I just learned how to create a lightmap to add ambient occlusion to my object by following this explanation:

[How do you bake ambient occlusion for a model?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13956/how-do-you-bake-ambient-occlusion-for-a-model)

Now I have a lightmap saved as an image (and currently mapped on my object), but I want to add a texture to my object as well. My texture is in an image file. I know how to add textures, but not overlaid ones. How do I do this in Blender Render?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to combine the baked AO texture with your texture using nodes.

[image]

- Make a copy of your initial object (on the picture the original is white on the left and the copy is yellow on the right)
- Assign a new material to the copy
- Select the copy and open the node editor (bottom part here)
- Add two textures : the baked one and yours (here i just used a full yellow texture)
- Add a MixRGB color operator and set it to "multiply"
- Connect them all as done on the picture

The result is shown on the top (in rendered mode)

Edit :

An alternative/better way in order to be closer to the original colors. It is using darken (MixRGB node) with a grey color (0.250). The darken effect is moderated by the inverted AOBacked texture.

[image]

Edit : for Blender Internal Render (same principle)

[image]

Comment: This is in Cycles. I'm working in Blender Render. I should have mentioned that.

Comment: Edited to add the equivalent for Blender Render

Comment: Thank you very much. I had just figured it out without using nodes, but this is far simpler. Now on to the next problem! :-)