# How can i change intensity of AO and bake this effect using blender render

Tags: uv, texture-baking

I'm ussing materials and UV mapping.I wanna export model and baked image to use in my game.

I've tried WorldTab>AO>Factor, no matter how i change factor 0.01 or 30.0 i get the same effect after bake. When i try n>Shading>AO there i can change AO strength but i don't know how bake this effect.
I get this: [image]
But i wanna effect like this:[image]

Comment: Cycles or internal?..

Comment: Internal.  I wanna get more intensive AO.

Comment: Try to lower the Attenuation to about 0.2 or so. It's in the world tab under Gather.

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/72516/increase-ambient-occlusion-effect

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- ### Pointiness node in Cycles

To have a full control over *AO* appearance you may use a ***Geometry (Pointiness)*** node with a *ColorRamp* to control the emission color and then bake it as a texture to use in *Blender Internal*. It only works in *Cycles* though.
[image]

In Cycles add a material to the unwrapped object and set up its material nodes as pictured below.
[image]

Use the *ColorRamp* node sliders to set the proportions between black and white emission colors. You may add several sliders there and change its mode for a different results.
[image]

To bake it as an *AO* map add a new texture in the *UV Editor* and call it e.g. *AO Baker*. In *Node Editor* add an *Image Texture* node and open the previously created *AO Baker* one there. With the *Texture* node ***selected***, go to *Render header*-->*Bake panel*. Set up the *bake type* to ***Emit*** and press the *Bake* button.
[image]

- ### Cavity Mask in Blender Internal Render (Texture Paint Mode)

To achieve similar functionallity as above in *Blender Render* you may create the ***cavity mask***. Using the curve you can control how soft or hard the *AO* looks like.
[image]

Go to *Texture Paint Mode* and add a new *diffuse texture slot*. Change the brush type to ***Fill*** and set it's color to black. In the *Options* bookmark check the ***Cavity Mask*** checkbox. Play with the curve below for different results (example below). Click the *'wrench icon'* to change the curve type to *Vector* e.g. for different results.
[image]